# HTML5, CSS: Make FA icon and link break correctly on mobile

Tags: html, css, font-awesome-5

When the first line breaks in mobile, I want to start let the second line start from where the first begins. Any ideas how to reach this on a list?

Codepen: https://codepen.io/altos/pen/KoKEba

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-download">     </i>
        <span class="file-title">Link 1 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr     </span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-download">     </i>
        <span class="file-title">Link 2 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr     </span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: I don t get what you want to achieve. Are you trying to overlap the two links? What have you tried so far?

Comment: See attached image, maybe this clears the questions https://imgur.com/a/cbh8H

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `display` properties to `a` to break on same line

```
ul li a {
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Sadly not. See attached image, maybe this clears the questions imgur.com/a/cbh8H

Comment: @Anuresh You are right! But now I have a really big gap between the links. How to fix that?

Comment: Oh right, it works there. At my test page I still had a css. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to achieve what you want is by using:

```
li{
list-style-image: url('/my-image')
}
```

But this would mean you need to have the image you need accessible on your server.

Another way would be:

```css
.fa-download{
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -1.5em;
}
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}
a:hover{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-download">     </i>
        <span class="file-title">Link 1 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr     </span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-download">     </i>
        <span class="file-title">Link 2 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr     </span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

using the second approach:

- remove the `list-style-type`.
- use the padding of the list to place the element
- the `<i class="fa fa-download"></i>` is at the start of your line.
- use `position: absolute` and `margin: -1.5em` to move the icon in the padding area of the list